# Spring: Get the form object after an ajax request

Tags: ajax, spring, forms

I try to submit a form in a ajax-way, with Spring. My code is :

FilterForm is a simple Bean with getters/setters.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mypage")
public class MyPageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("filterForm", new FilterForm());
        return "configuration/home";
     }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String filter(@ModelAttribute FilterForm filterForm, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("filterForm", filterForm);
        return "fragments/configuration/filter-result";
    }
}
```

The view home.html is:

```
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/mypage/filter}" th:object="${filterForm}" method="post" id="filterForm">
            <p>Field : <input type="text" th:field="*{field}" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
        </form>

        <div id="filterResults"></div>
```

The view filter-result is (by now):

```
<span th:text="${filterForm.getField()}"></span>
```

With only that, it works fine. But it isn't ajax. To submit the form in an ajax-way, it use:

```
$("#filterForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            dataType : 'html',
            data : frm.serialize(),
            success : function(callback){
                $("#filterResults").html(callback);
            },
            error : function(e){
                console.log('error');
                console.log(e.status + ' ' + e.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
```

In this case, the attributes of filterForm, in the filter method, are null. In firebug, I can see that POST params are well formed, ie "field=anything". Can't figure why Spring cannot bind the request to the filterForm when it is ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of this line contentType : `application/json; charset=utf-8`